# Shiny does not show results in the app but results are shown in the console

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an R shiny app to produce k-means clustering results. The app is not producing results. However, it  shows output in the console. Further, it also works fine when it knitted in Rmarkdown. If you have any opinion on the code part or any other suggestion to resolve this issue. Do let me know.

Here is my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(cluster)



ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Cluster Analysis"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    helpText("You will be able to see the variable name after you add in a datafile"),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,checkboxGroupInput("variable","Select Variables:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
    ),
    sliderInput("kvalue", "Select number of clusters", 
                value = 3, min = 3, max= 6),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
        uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Result", verbatimTextOutput("result")),
      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents'))
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  dsnames <- c()

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return()

    data_set <-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, 
                       sep=input$sep)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({data_set()})

  observe({
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "variable",
                             label = "Select Variables",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
  })
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  dfInput <- reactive({
    data <- data_set()

    if(is.null(data))
      return()

    data %>%
      dplyr::select(input$variable)
    }
)
  output$result <- renderPrint(
    {
      dfin <- dfInput()
      gp <- NULL

      if (!is.null(dfin)){
            df <- dfin
            test <- na.omit(df)
            test1 <- scale(test)
            test2 <- daisy(test1)
            seg.k <- kmeans(test2, centers=input$kvalue, nstart=25)
            df$segment <- seg.k$cluster 
            test2 <- df%>%
            dplyr::group_by(segment)%>%
            dplyr::summarise_all(list(mean))
            print(test2)
      }
      return(gp)
    }
  )
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    colnames <- names(contents)
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can we have a sample of your data to work with (or can you adapt this one to work with an available dataset, e.g., the `iris` dataset)? And to be clear, is the issue that you're not seeing results displayed in the table ("contents") or in the text output ("result"), or both?

Comment: @phalteman the app should work with any csv data file. I am not able to get the display in the table("result") part.

Comment: For some reasons, it works now. I added `transpose` function to the output table ("result"). Thanks for going through the document @phalteman.